# Whats the best way to delete a record in this specific case?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have this table in `SQL`/`ORACLE`/`INFORMIX` with this columns:

```
Table: Lot
Columns: Id, Status and ProcessList
```

So, my column ProcessList store a varchar like this:

```
(1,2,3,7,12)
```

I need to remove a record from `Lot` Table, by a unique process like this pseudoexample:

```
Delete from Lot where ProcessList contains process 7
```

How I can do this?

Comment: The best solution by far is to change your database schema. Storing data as a comma-separated list is one of the worst things you can do in a RDBMS (<rant> topped only by dumping Java objects as BLOBs, using a "generic" key-value approach or storing everything as XML </rant> ).

Comment: So, this is both `SQL SERVER` and `ORACLE` *(and `INFORMIX` as well?)* at the same time?  And involves storing multiple facts in a single field?  Scary.

Comment: First of all that's a worst DB design and try Normalize your table. your table is not even in 1NF.

Answer (score 2):

If you absolutely cannot change the schema (which is preferable), this should work:

```
DELETE FROM Lot
WHERE ProcessList LIKE '%,7,%' -- number is in middle of list
OR ProcessList LIKE '%,7)' -- number is at the end of a list
OR ProcessList LIKE '(7,%' -- number is at the start of the list
OR ProcessList LIKE '(7)' -- number is the only item in the list
```

Comment: @DanielE. Yes, I've made a tweak

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
delete from Lot where 
    ProcessList like '(7,%' or 
    ProcessList like '%,7)' or 
    ProcessList like '%,7,%' or 
    ProcessList = '(7)';
```

Query assumes there is no whitespaces between the `process_id` and the comma sign and no whitespaces between `process_id` and closing brace. And, that `ProcessList` is a text field :)

As you see, query becomes not very easy to read with all possible cases added. You way want to reconsider storing values like that (as suggested in comments) because it is *really* hard to work with such a string.

Comment: @LucasAbilidebob You're right. I have updated the query to fix that issue. Same assumptions - no whitespaces between anything.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but for the case (7) its not work

Comment: @LucasAbilidebob Fixed that too.

Comment: @AlexeyMalev you have a minor typo for the case where number is at the start of the list

Comment: @DavidG I believe you were referring to me. Thanks, fixed.